# How to restore Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, restore, compiz, desktop-environments

A few days back, I installed Compiz to try out the 3D desktop effects. Unfortunately, that messed up my desktop, and it has since been working in low resolution mode.

Can someone suggest a quick restore mechanism to get my desktop display back to normal?

Comment: You tried System > Preferences > Display, right?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to go to the recovery menu at startup to fix the graphics problem. It worked once before when I tried graphical elements that my laptop couldn't handle and one setting just made the screen go blank

Answer (score 1):

This happens many times here - trying Linux options & apps.  I simply re-install Ubuntu.  It 'remembers' my previous settings. Since my notebook hardware cannot handle COMPIZ, it will not allow me to install it at all.  No Compix 11.04 on my simple Intel I3 cpu.  :-(

When reinstalling, use the manual partition setup.  Select exactly the same ROOT, BOOT & SWAP partitions are the previous setup.  ROOT is about 16 gigabytes, since it has most of the folders of Linux.  BOOT is 512 megabytes.  SWAP is 4 GB, enough for hibernation if needed.